# How to Write Output Files from a JAR Program to Directory Outside the JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io

tl;dr I'm more used to writing command-line scripts that can just output based on the current working directory, so I'm unsure what directory to use for output files in a program that will be launched from a JAR.

### Program Description:

My program builds an HTML file from data given to it from the rest of the program, and then is supposed to write it to a file that we'll call "Output.html" for simplicity.

### Relevant Code:

```java
public void outputHTML()
{
    String output = buildHTML();
    
    // Expanded to explain my confusion better
    String fileDirectory = ""; // ???
    String fileName = "Output.html";
    
    String fullPath = fileDirectory + "\\" + fileName;
    
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fullPath)))
    {
        writer.write(output);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Problem

I don't know what to put the file directory as.  Usually I run my programs from the command line and use ".\\Output.txt" as my output path, but I don't know where to put it if it's being run from a JAR.

The desired file structure is as follows:

- Encompassing Folder

  - Program.jar
  - output

    - Output.html

Or alternatively (not sure if this makes it easier to understand or harder):

- main\

  - main\Program.jar
  - main\output\

    - main\output\Output.html

Everything I can find on SE only relates to *reading* files that are both *immutable* and *internal*, but I'm trying to output a non-static file to a location outside of my jar.

Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

### Misc Details

I'm using Eclipse without Gradle currently, because I don't know what Gradle is and new things are scary.  If this particular problem would be easier to solve with Gradle, let me know and I'll look up more about it.

#### EDIT:

- Added syntax highlighting to code block.
- Formatted everything a bit better
- Changed title to be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

You can use an absolute path: e.g. `fileDirectory = "\\project\\test\\main\\output";`
using normal slash should also work even on Windows (`"/project/test/main/output"`)

Or use a relative path - this will start from the current working directory (user directory), the one where the JVM was started in - e.g. `fileDirectory = "main\\output";`

Comment: What is the working directory for a jar program anyway?  I've only ever thought of working directories being usable in the command line, not when running a program from an executable, etc.

Comment: "the one where the JVM was started in" - that is the directory where the `java` or `java.exe` is executed from. You can print the result of `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see what it is. "running from an executable"?

Comment: Ok, so that definitely wouldn't be a good convention for writing output files, right?  I'm not trying to write my files to the user's PATH lol.  For that last bit, I was (incorrectly?) lumping jar files and executables together, since I've always thought of them as similar.

Comment: Now that I think about it, is there a way to get the absolute directory of the jar and jump around using that?

Comment: when double-clicking on the JAR normally (system dependent)  the directory where the JAR is, is the working directory. To get the absolute path `new File("").getAbsolutePath()`